# Split pandas Dataframe into n equal parts + 1

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas Dataframe containing 44150 rows.

I want to split into sub-dataframes each containing 100 rows except the last that has to contain 50.

I've tried using **`numpy.array_split`** but it's splitting it into 392 dataframes of size 100 and 50 dataframes of size 99.

Is there anyway to split it the way I want?

Comment: When you give `array_split` a number it splits the `DataFrame` into that many equal parts, or as close to equal parts as it can make. You can also provide it with a list of indices to split on `[S*x for x in range(1, N+1)]` using @Abramodj's solution, for instance

Comment: See also the many pandas answers on `chunking`. (Btw, if you want to do this at read-time, you could read in chunks of 100 lines.)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `iloc` and a list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x':np.random.randn(44150),
    'y':np.random.randn(44150),
})

S = 100
N = int(len(df)/S)
frames = [ df.iloc[i*S:(i+1)*S].copy() for i in range(N+1) ]
```

The last DataFrame - which can be found in `frames[-1]` - has 50 rows, while the other ones have 100.

Comment: Why did you use ```copy()``` ?